# My cron job is failing, however the script is executing fine otherwise. Can someone help here?

Tags: shell, cron

My below script is executing perfectly while running it manually but it is failing in cron job and getting the following error:

`Item_Loc_Soh_Snapshot batch failed.`

Can someone help me here?

```
#!/bin/ksh
# Script variables
programName=$0
date=`date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`
logFile=$0.log
#echo $UP
sqlplus -s $UP << EOF > ${logFile}

truncate table rms132.item_loc_soh_snapshot;
insert into rms132.item_loc_soh_snapshot (select * from item_loc_soh);
commit;

EOF

#Verifying the program execution

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
   echo "Successfully Excuted the Item_Loc_Snapshot Batch.">> ${logFile}
else
   echo "Item_Loc_Soh_Snapshot batch failed.">> ${logFile}
   exit -1
fi
```

Comment: Consider  adding 'set -x' to the top of the file, so it will be possible to see which command is failing, and possible missing variables. No other errors from sqlplus ? How  is UP setup ? how is the connection authenticated ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the settings in environment when you run it via cron:

```
#!/bin/ksh
# Script variables
source ~/.profile
```

This is the way to ensure you have `ORACLE_SID` and other variables set when you run it in `cron`

Also check where is set the variable `UP`

Answer (score 0):

This is general answer for many CRON problems:

Consider modifying the cron command line to redirect the STDERR and STDOUT to file, usually having date (or timestamp) attached to them. Place them into a log file, and do regular purging. This will leave you with lot of information on problems.

```
1 1 1 1 1 command >>log/command.$(date +%F).out 2>>log/command.$(date +%F).err
```